# What does "Password for deploy@fosinfo:" mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano, passenger, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to deploy a rails app using the tutorial [here](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) and I am getting

```
Password for deploy@fosinfo:
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Could you provide more details? When exactly do you get it?

Comment: When I run cap production deploy

Comment: Could you attach the output of `cap production deploy --trace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the

```
config/deploy/production.rb
```

I has entered the wrong IP address.